# Flutter Dart.io Process Class Hanging

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, process

Just going back to a codebase I had up and running some 3 months ago. It uses dart.io to call Process to shell out and do a curl call to download a bunch of files.  This used to work but now does not. I'm not sure when it broke, it was just a bug that I assumed I'd fix later. Typically it would download around 14 of the 250 files and then just hang the Flutter App.  Debug won't pause, and I have a breakpoint prior to the Process call and after it.  To make sure it wasn't the Curl itself I removed that and just put a very simple process ls -l call in it's place. It does the same thing, after after 15 calls (whether sync or async) it just hangs the Fluter app. I updated everything, did an outdated, did a clean.  Any thoughts?

```
var result =  await Process.run('ls', ['-l']);


[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem running tests. If I put some Process.start call into setUp and/or tearDown, after some call the test hangs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).